# Compact but not measurable

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Does there exist a compact subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ (with the usual topology) which is not Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: Three upvotes? ${}$

Answer (score 8):

No. The Heine Borel theorem says that compact sets are closed in $\mathbb R^n $, and closed sets are Borel sets, so they are Lebesgue mearurable.

Comment: Remark: the Heine-Borel theorem is overkill. In any Hausdorff (and hence metric) space compact sets are closed. No need for special theorems. The force of Heine-Borel is saying that in fact closed and bounded are sufficient for compactness under the Euclidean metric.